# Any equivalent of sorted data structures like ConcurrentSkipList of Java or Map/Set of C++ in Python?

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, python-3.x, data-structures

Currently, I am working on a problem where events with certain sequence numbers arrive at the server. The arrive in proper sequence, but may get processed out of order. While acking back, I have to ensure that I ack the even with highest sequence number which doesn't have a un-processed event before. I.e. if I ack 100, that means events 0 to 100 are processed, but event 101 yet to get processed.

I am keeping the sequence numbers in in list (sorted) in Python. I keep popping the processed band of events from the beginning of the list and so. The number of events that the process may be working on may be huge (100000 or so) and hence keeping all their sequence numbers in the list may be a performance issue, then popping some elements from the beginning of the list may also have performance issues, locating an element in the list also a performance issue as it will be a linear search.

Is there set/map/concurrentskiplist equivalent in Python? Python set doesn't keep the items sorted as in case with C++ set from STL.

Comment: Have you looked at the heapq module?

Comment: Hmm, after re-reading the question, I think that collections.deque might probably be better.  You would like to keep them in order the whole time if you could, right?

Comment: Yes. I have to keep them in order.

Comment: Raymond Hettinger implemented an efficient skip list in Python and tested for Python 2.5, 2.6 and 3.1.  According to him, value insert, removal and lookup are all O(ln n).  The code is at http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576930/.